# speed up append to jTextArea in java swing when loading a lot of text

Tags: java, swing

I'm using **JavaSwing** for UI. I'm having to put a lot of text inside of a `jTextArea`; loading anywhere from 500KB to 5MB of text file into the `jTextArea`

```sh
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("filename.txt"));
txtarea.read(br,null);
br.close;
txtarea.requestFocus();
```

but when read `filename.txt` then append to text area is very slow.
I tried append `txtarea.append(String text)` or `txtarea.setText(String text)` but it unimproved and very slowly.

Thanks for any attention in advance!

Comment: Where did you get `txtArea.read(br, null)`? I mean, there is no such a method in [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Comment: @matoni I think it refers to the [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-) method inherited from `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent`

Comment: @ThumChoonTat you are right :). Try to to employ `SwingWorker` which would be continously appending text chunks (that were read from file) in textArea  (check also if `repaint()` is invoked automatically on append so you can see the progress).

Comment: Or at least use the `SwingWorker` to do the reading and then set the text on the component in one go. It looks like the implementation of  `JTextComponent.read` does its work on the Swing GUI thread, which isn't helping things.